# Capture select frames from a video on iphone (back Camera)

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I am very new to iOs and cocoa framework.

The UIImagePickerControl allows me to shoot a video using the back camera and flip through the frames of the video once recording is complete.

I would like to select few of those frames as images to used later ('n' images).

Would I be correct to say that I would have to use AVFoundation classes to do the above?

I wanted to be sure that I am not overlooking some simple option due to my lack of knowledge.

Would I have to build my own control to allow the user to select multiple frames (not necessarily consecutive) as output images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVFoundation classes are the way to go if one has to do anything custom with the video output. In my case it was selecting frames.

Used AVFoundation to capture the video frames and used scroll viewer functionality to select specific frames.